# Outlook.MailItem - Is there any way to determine if two mailitems (sent to different recipients) are the same?

Tags: c#, outlook, comparison

I would like to know if there is any way to compare two `Outlook.MailItem`s to see if they are the same.

For example, If two people in our company receive the same email, is there a way to compare them for equality?

I was thinking about comparing the the folowing properties:

`Subject`, `To`, `From`, `CC`, `Body`

which may work 99% of the time, however as the database grows bigger and bigger this routine will become slower and slower.

Is there a better way to acheive this?

Comment: Hey Simon I am also want to Compare Subject, To, From, CC, Body Which approach did you used to achieve this ?

Comment: the mailHash method seems to be the best way, store it in the DB and put an index on the column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are storing the values, then a hashcode of the properties might be the way to go, using the properties you stated.  You could then make this an indexed column to improve search and retrieval performance.

So I guess in C# :

```
var mailHash = String.Format("{0}{1}{2}{3}{4}", mail.To, mail.From, mail.CC, mail.Subject, mail.Body).GetHashCode();
```

Would that work for you?

Cheers,
Chris.

Comment: Cheers - glad to be of service! :)

Comment: Expanding on this, if you need to use a standard hash, you could also use SHA256.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than creating your own hash function, you should use the one really used by the system. In the case of Exchange items, you can check the item's [EntryID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.entryid.aspx) to get the Exchange ID for the item. I think it will be unique for a local PST as well, but you should make sure of that.

Comment: Sorry, ive read that EntryID is not unique, whereby it can change when moving the MailItem between folders

Comment: Not between folders, between stores. It remains identical as long as it's in an Exchange mailbox - any mailbox. But if you move it to a PST file or to a public folder, it can change. But if you're comparing items in corporate folders, it can be a good indicator.

Comment: The String implementation of GetHashCode() should be sufficient for this.  Granted, even the documentation admits that there isn't a unique hash code for all unique strings - but equally, I've yet to run into a collision for two unique strings.  And, if you wanted to write your own hash function, I'm sure that wheel has already been invented! :)

Comment: Won't the EntryID be different for two recipients though - same message, but different mailboxes?!

Comment: I don't think so. An email sent to several recipient is only stored once in the Exchange database, and should have the same EntryID, as far as I know.

Comment: As taken from MSDN : "A MAPI store provider assigns a unique ID string when an item is created in its store. Therefore, the EntryID property is not set for a Microsoft Outlook item until it is saved or sent. The EntryID changes when an item is moved into another store, for example, from your Inbox to a Microsoft Exchange Server public folder, or from one Personal Folders (.pst) file to another .pst file. Solutions should not depend on the EntryID property to be unique unless items will not be moved."